# Error in GraphQL converting DB int to Enum using nodejs

Tags: node.js, enums, graphql, resolver

I am trying to return a DB int value as a GraphQL enum.

My database returns

```
{"manufacturer":"Ford","model":"F-150","carType":4}
```

But when I run my query, I get the error:

```
Enum "CarType" cannot represent value 4.
```

If my type has carType as Int!, it works as expected. But it is unable to resolve 4 as the CarType enum value of SUV.

What am I missing? The goal is to return an int value from the database as a GraphQL enum value.

Test code:

```
module.exports.typeDefs = graphql `
    extend type Query {
        cars: [Car]
    }
    type Car{
        manufacturer:String!
        model:String!
        carType:CarType
        }
    enum CarType{
        COUPE
        SEDAN
        CROSSOVER
        TRUCK
    }
        

`
module.exports.resolvers = {
    CarType: {
        COUPE: 1,
        SEDAN:2,
        CROSSOVER:3,
        TRUCK:4
      },
    Query: {
        cars: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            let lst = [{"manufacturer":"Ford","model":"F-150","carType":4}]
            return lst;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the resolver of the enum is not running. It's failing because it's trying to map the value 4 but when I look at the definition of the enum during debugging, the values are the same as the names - which is the default for enums, but which I expected should have been resolved by the resolver. If I send back the value "TRUCK" for carType, it is fine, but not the value 4.

Also, the examples here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/scalars-enums/

deal with enums as query inputs, not resolving them as they go back to the client. I was wondering if there was a different way to resolve integers to enums when going back to the client.

Comment: Fixed a typo in sample code where the enum didn't have the correct value. The error happens when the enum value is present in the enum and the resolver.

Comment: The code above appears to be correct, so the issue may be how you're incorporating the enum value map into your resolver map. You may be importing or merging the code incorrectly, or the resolverMap may be the wrong shape. Please show the complete code.

Comment: Thank you - I added the test  - it's very simple. But it doesn't recognize 4 as a valid enum value.

Comment: That code works as expected. See [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-snow-9zh7u). I copied and pasted your typeDefs and resolvers and just removed the `extend` keyword. Where ever the problem is, it's not with the posted code. That's why I was suggesting it could be an issue with how you're importing or merging your resolvers. Please post a repo link or a link to a sandbox where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you for that analysis - that makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, I cannot expose the corporate sandbox, but at least I have direction on where to look for the issue. Thanks a lot for your help. I will post back once it's figured out.